# Is it possible/good/worthwhile trying to get older questions to the front so that new users see them?

Tags: discussion, questions

This is probably an issue just because the site is young but I still keep coming to great older questions that I missed and that haven't received the attention they should've.

This is because I joined the site few weeks after it launched, so I missed some of those early questions. And so did lots of other people who joined later. Is there any direct mechanism for bringing these older questions into the front so that they can get attention (and in particular votes)? I can think of few procedures, but every one of them has certain problems:

1. I can edit either the question or some answer. But this is just a work-around and I am not sure it's polite towards other, newer questions (not to mention towards author of the post I am editing).
2. I can provide a new answer. Again, this is not what I want to do in general: there might already be a good answer (or more of them) but I'd like more people to come and check them (and provide votes, most importantly).
3. I can make the question featured. This feels again work-aroundish. Because I don't really want to award any bounty. I just want people to come and look at the question and answers already provided.

Of these three approaches I think 3. is the best but it doesn't really solve the problem.

So here are the questions:

> 1. Do we want to get older questions that (lot of) people missed to the front?
> 2. If so, what is the best way to accomplish it?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's desirable to get old question to the front as a general rule. As far as I know, there is a blurry hierarchy for the questions, but the top level goes to unanswered questions (we don't have a problem there right now). However, don't you think that one of the first things that people do when joining a new site is to check out the old stuff, in this case, the old questions?).

Comment: @Robert: I honestly don't know whether it's good but there are some good questions that went quite unnoticed. As for going over the old stuff: I don't know. There is 600 questions on the site right now; there's quite a lot old stuff to go over and to spot a good question is not easy. As I said, I am still discovering some nice older questions purely accidentally despite having gone over them before (not thoroughly, of course).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system actually does this automatically, to some extent - it randomly "bumps" an old question every once in a while. I don't remember the details of which questions are eligible or how often this happens, but I bet there's a post on MSO describing it. I'll edit in a link if I find it.

I don't think we really need to get old questions up to the front of the site that much, though. People can only focus on so much content at a time, and given that I think we'd rather have everyone's attention *mainly* on the new questions which need to be answered. People will occasionally go back and browse old questions on their own.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this answers my question completely. If I'll have a feeling that some question particularly needs to get to the top, I'll put a bounty on it myself.